# Unable to install/remove mongodb-org on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic - "mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not installed"

Tags: node.js, linux, mongodb, ubuntu

I've tried following the instructions to install mongodb, as per [the mongodb.com instructions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/).

When I run: `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`, I get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not going to be installed
```

There's a suggestion to run `apt --fix-broken install`. So I run it with `sudo`. I get the following:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.65.1 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongo-tools
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mongodb-database-tools
```

Which then fails, with this error report:

```
Unpacking mongodb-database-tools (100.5.0) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.5.0_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mongodb-database-tools_100.5.0_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

My reading of this: `trying to overwrite '/usr/bin/bsondump', which is also in package mongo-tools 3.6.3-0ubuntu1` suggests to me that there is something in `mongo-tools` that is stubbornly not letting itself be removed. So I tried running `sudo apt autoremove` to remove the `mongo-tools`. Unfortunately I get the following:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 mongodb-org-tools : Depends: mongodb-database-tools but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

So I try `apt --fix-broken install` again, as recommended, but without any success. I need to find a way to get rid of that darned `mongo-tools` - but how? I tried following the "Uninstall MongoDB Community Edition" instructions on those on the same page I linked above.

When I enter `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`, this forms part of the message:

```
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libboost-program-options1.65.1 libgoogle-perftools4 libpcrecpp0v5 libtcmalloc-minimal4 libyaml-cpp0.5v5 mongo-tools mongodb-mongosh
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
```

So now I have `mongo-tools` and this new `mongodb-mongosh`? I've attempted to install again but I run into the same problems. What's the fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working: I tried `sudo apt-get purge mongo-tools*` and `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-mongosh*`, and this seemed to fix things and permit an install.

For some reason, the uninstall directions in the documentation (command: `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`) didn't remove `mongo-tools`. It may have been something I'd installed from another source previously.

Comment: In previous release `mongo-tools` was part of the mongo server package, now they are two distinct packages. Perhaps this caused the conflict.

Answer (score 1):

1.Stop the `mongod` process by issuing the following command:-

```
    sudo service mongod stop
```

2.Remove any MongoDB packages that you had previously installed:-

```
    sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

3.Remove MongoDB databases and log files:-

```
    sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
    sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

4.Then reinstall mangodb 4.4.8

5.Import the public key used by the package management system:-

```
    wget -qO - https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-4.4.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

6.The following instruction is for Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic):-

```
    echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.4.list
```

7.Update Apt

```
    sudo apt-get update
```

8.Install mongodb

```
    sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=4.4.8 mongodb-org-server=4.4.8 mongodb-org-shell=4.4.8 mongodb-org-mongos=4.4.8 mongodb-org-tools=4.4.8
```

9.Use `mongod --version` to check its succesfully installed.

10.If u encounter any error while using `mongod`

```
    sudo mkdir /data
    cd /data
    sudo mkdir db
    sudo pkill -f mongod
```

11.Then use `sudo mongod` command to start server.

12.Use `mongo` to use mongodb shell